# Stop Off without Leaving Airport

Tags: layovers, short-connections, slc

We will be flying from Atlanta to SLC to pick up our three children, who spent the week with their Aunt. There is a great deal on a flight that arrives at 1:22pm and then departs the same airport at 2:22pm, which only gives us an hr to catch the second flight. I have already confirmed with the airline that the kids can get through TSA on their own and meet us at the gate.

I'm hoping I can just print my boarding pass for the return flight back to Atlanta online and walk to the gate without having to leave the airport. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you even need to _print_? Most airlines seem to do mobile boarding passes these days.

Comment: Yes! That was my thinking too, didn't mean to say print. Just wanted to make sure there was no reason why the airline would make me go through security again. I don't travel much so I have little experience with current regulations.

Comment: x @AJC: I think this would _typically_ be possible (that is, arriving domestic passengers disembark into the sterile departure area), especially since SLC is a hub airport -- but I don't know if there'd be special issues that would be a problem at that airport in particular.

Comment: Note that if SLC is a hub for the airline you're flying with, you shouldn't expect your outbound flight to be the same aircraft as the inbound one -- in particular if your flight _towards_ Salt Lake City is late, the flight _back_ could leave before you arrive, and then you'd probably be on your own if your tickets were bought as return tickets rather than a connection.

Comment: Do you have contingency plans for late arrival of your flight or delay in the children getting through TSA?

Comment: @HenningMakholm US domestic terminals generally do not separate arrivals and departures, except for international arrivals, so it's likely they can remain airside.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Yes, that's the _typical_ case I was describing. But I don't know positively whether SLC is an exception or not.

Comment: @HenningMakholm From the [map](https://www.slcairport.com/maps/airport-terminal-map/) it appears all the terminals are connected airside, except the international terminal. So as long as they're on a domestic flight both ways, they should not have to go through security.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks! I am aware that we can't do much if our outbound flight is delayed, but it helps knowing I won't have to deal with TSA again (most likely).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get boarding passes for both flights at the same time.  Most U.S. airlines allow you to do online checkin 24 hours before your flights, so at 2:22 PM the day before your flights, you should be able to checkin for both flights and print both boarding passes.  If you are not able to checkin online, when you arrive at the airport to fly to SLC, you can check in for both flights at the counter.